# people's age calcuation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table called person with id, name, dob   3 columns, 
sample data follows:

```
INSERT INTO person(id,name,dob) VALUES
   (1,'Ton','1964-01-02'),
   (2,'Luck','1960-01-20').....

select
   name, dob,
   current_timestamp() as curren_date,
   timestampdiff(year, dob, curdate()) as age,
   timestampdiff(month, dob, curdate()) as age,
   timestampdiff(day, dob, curdate()) as age,
   date_format(dob, '%m'),
   month(curdate()),
   timestampdiff(month,  date_format(dob, '%m'),month(curdate())),
   DATEDIFF(dob, curdate()) AS DateDiff

from
    person
```

So i don't know what i miss, the above code can calculate the age in years- not very accurate i believe, but ideally i want to calculate the people's age in year, month, days,  e.g Ton 55 years 1 month 3 days, and also want to calculate his next birthday due date, e.g next birthday date: 11 month 10 days left etc

Thanks

Comment: Your current use of `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is probably the most concise way to go here.  What is wrong with it?

Comment: thanks, i would like to have output, e.g Tom's age is 55 years 1 month 3 days old, and next birthday will be 11 months 10 days left, so my above code only gives me the rough age (years), not year+ month+ days

Comment: Your requirements seem ambiguous.  If someone is born June 30th and it is now August 1st, what are the months and days of their age?

Comment: if  a new baby was born e.g last month, then sql will be calculate as 0 year age for her, that's not concise...

Comment: @ysth   yeah, agree, that's why need help from community

Comment: If you want help from community, ok: from my perspective, age is in years.  Trying to make up some definition of age in months and days is silly

Comment: What's wrong with the textbook solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the age in years accurately as:

```
select (case when date_format(dob, '%m-%d') >= date_format(now(), '%m-%d')
             then year(now()) - year(dob)
             else year(now()) - year(dob) - 1
        end)
```

I believe that this handles all edge cases -- such as leap years.  It accurately counts the age up to the day.

I've never been a fan of years/months/days, because I think the definition is unclear.  You will need to provide sample of what you want.